# Throw cascaded Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to pass multiple error messages to the GUI. How do I have to do this? Please have a short look at my abstract example above:

```
try
{
    LogIn(usr, pwd); //entry point
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Login failed.");
}



public void LogIn(string usr, string pwd) {

    if(usr == "") {
        throw new Exception("Username was empty.");
    }

    if(pwd== "") {
        throw new Exception("Password was empty.");
    }

    try
    {
        //do some other stuff without a more specific error message
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }  
}
```

Later I would like to get a result error message like

> Login failed. Password was empty.

if the user didn't type in a password. Right now I just get the last error message ("login failed.") on top and so just half of my information that I would like to give to the user.

Comment: As a personal preference, I do prefer using more specific exception types. I would change it to `ArgumentNullException("Username was empty")` and throw it before calling the `Login` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rethink your structure. 
As in the comments pointed out there are some things to consider:

- Will the method called elsewhere and could so lead to wrong usage?
- If I use exceptions in my flow control, could it lead to unreadable code? ([Using exceptions for flow control](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/02/26/exceptions-for-flow-control-in-c/))

#### Approach with `List<string>` for collecting issues:

```
public void LogIn(string usr, string pwd) 
{   
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(usr)) 
    {
        errors.Add("Username is empty.");
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd)) 
    {
        errors.Add("Password is empty.");
    }   

    if(errors.Count > 0) // If errors occur, throw exception.
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Join("\r\n",errors));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Exception handling in .NET is to improve upon error handling of old where one would need to **remember** to check return values of a called method or function.   Checking a list of strings sounds like a bad idea

Comment: You could even throw this Exception inside `LogIn` method. You can also create own Exception type (i.e. `class LoginException : Exception` that would encapsulate the list of errors). 
But beware of [Using exceptions for flow control](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/02/26/exceptions-for-flow-control-in-c/).

Comment: @MickyD - on the other hand, *validation* errors are hardly *exceptional*, and so using exceptions here is questionable.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `ArgumentNullException`. QED.  Considering [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51720341/585968) is throwing exceptions I find your conclusion perplexing

Comment: @MickyD - `ArgumentNullException` is an exception reporting a *programmer* error. This code is dealing with *user* errors. My answer was providing an answer to the question as written. It doesn't mean that it's the only possible viewpoint, and it so happens that I also agree with Smartis's take on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can *nest* exceptions:

```
try
{
    LogIn(usr, pwd); //entry point
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Login failed.", ex);
}
```

Note the second argument, and the `InnerException` property of [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx).

But before doing do, consider whether the above block is *adding any value*. If you just let the `Password was empty` exception escape instead, the caller would still know, generically, that the login has failed, and that exception alone seems to contain all the required information.

Only `catch` an exception if you have something *useful* to do - if you can recover an error condition, add information or do not want to expose implementation details to your callers. Otherwise, let the exceptions rise to a level where something useful *can* be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `ex.Message` which would either be *Password was empty.* or *Username was empty.*